# Am I likely to experience less Azure Spot VM instance evictions by creating it in a region that has a large time difference from where it's used?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I am creating a spot VM to be used in offices located in New York. If I choose India as the region, will the time difference between the two regions help reduce the spot evictions because I can expect peak hours in India to be off peak hours in New York and vice versa?

Comment: That sounds logical. But the cure might be worse than the disease if your workload is sensitive to latency. The sheer distance between New York and India will guarantee a  round trip latency of 200 milliseconds or more

Comment: This did occur to me, but latency is not a problem in my case.